# How to add new text in all a tag href [Update]

Tags: javascript, jquery, customization, href

I have 20 `<a>` tag link, the href like this

```
<a href="/item/sdfs/saf/sf/sf"></a>
```

They are listed under ul li

```
<ul class="someclass">
    <li>
        <a href="/item/sdfs/saf/sf/sf"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a website link in href like this

```
<a href="website.com/item/sdfs/saf/sf/sf"></a>
```

I found solution

```
$("ul.portfolio_sec li a").each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('href').replace('/item','https://www.website.net/item/');            
        //var a = $('<a/>').attr('href', src);
        $(this).attr('href', src);
        $(this).attr('target', "_blank");
        //console.log(src);
    });
```

And it's working great

Comment: Are you asking how to add it dynamically or how to add a hard coded text in the list

Comment: Do you want to add `href` to all `a` tags ?

Comment: I want to add dynamically via jquery or php @CrazyMac

Comment: Yeah to all href under ul @Leopard

Comment: Get the reference to ul through Jquery and keep appending the list.. Something like below,

$('ul').append('<li>....</li>')

Comment: why do you need this? I don't see the reason to change dynamically the link to absolute...

Answer (score 0):

You can select all of them and prepend the `website.com` before the rest of the URL:

```
$('.someclass a').each(function(index, a){
    a.href = 'website.com' + a.href;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can do this

```
$('.someclass li a').attr("href", "http://www.google.com");
```